# Javascript: Name and mail validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, email

so what i need to do is to set up some code to validate name and e-mail. If the fields are empty an alert is supposed to appear, and also if you fail to fill in a valid e-mail adress.

I'm not sure I'm doing this right. It's also worth noting that I have minimum experience with javascript.

```
function test(email, name) {

    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")

    {
        alert("You forgot to enter name or email");
        return false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")

    {
        alert("You forgot to enter name or email");
        return false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)

    {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: Ummm A variable cannot have a dash ("-") in it.

Comment: Well. What happens when you run this? Does it work?

Comment: No i do not get the result i want.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into use the string.match function of JS. There are many examples of using this function to validate an email address using a Regex.

Comment: @AndrewP you should take care when validating email addresses. Many of the email validation plugins and RegExp fail for domains with unicode letters (supported by using Punycode).

Answer (score 2):

For email validation your should use regexp which will validate RFC 2822 standard. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Also you can use [jQuery.validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org), if jQuery its ok to you.

And you can use HTML5 Form Validation, like

```
<input type="email" name="e-mail" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, can't believe that didn't pop up for me on google

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has form validation built in, so you won't even need to use JavaScript. You can use this feature if you're developing for IE10+, Chrome, or Firefox ([caniuse.net](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation)).

To produce an error message when a field is empty:

```
 <input type="text" id="email" required>
```

To require input to be in a certain pattern (e.g. email address):

```
<input type="text" id="name" pattern="[a-z]">
```

You can put in your preferred regular expression for email validation in the "pattern" attribute. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) for a valuable discussion.